# PHP/mySQL For Loop not always running so values remain unchanged in DB

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a function that is called to update a table in mysql.  The problem is that even though it always runs, sometimes it will not modify the values that it's supposed to... i.e if the for loop is supposed to run 4 times it will run 3 and exit, so 1 of the values remains unchanged.

the function:

```
        function update_inventory(){ 
        require_once 'admin_connect.php';
        $mysqli_escape = function($str) use ($mysqli) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $str);
        };

        $upc = array_map($mysqli_escape, $_POST['upc']);
                for($i=0;$i<count($upc);$i++){
                    if($upc[$i] != ''){ 

        $update_query = "UPDATE inventory SET inInv = inInv -1 WHERE UPC = '". $upc[$i] ."'";
        $run_update = mysqli_query($mysqli,$update_query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        $last_key = $last_key + 1;
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['inventory_out'] = $last_key;             
    }
```

In short... it will always run but sometimes exit before updating the last record.

The code where I run it:

```
    if(isset($_POST)){
        if(isset($_POST['upc']) && isset($_POST['name'])){  
        insert_products();
        header( 'Location: ../index.php' );
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['sel'])){ 
        db_select();
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['upc']) && isset($_POST['area'])){
        update_inventory();
        header( 'Location: ../out.php');
                }
        }
        else { 
        header( 'Location: ../in.php' ) ;
        }
```

Where the POST happens

```
<div id="body">
<form action="includes/connection_functions.php" method="post">

        <table for=record>

        <th>Item Number</th>
        <th for=c>UPC</th>
        <?php       

        for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++){ 
                echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$i.'</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="upc[]" value="" size="50" /></td>
                </tr>
                ';
        }

        ?>
                   </table>
                            <div for=select>
                            <select name="area">
                            <option value="Desayuno">Desayuno
                            </option><option value="Almuerzo">Almuerzo
                            </option><option value="Cena">Cena</option></select>
                            <input type="reset" value="clear" />
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                            </div>


</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this happen every time it runs or just isolated cases?

Comment: Can we see what is in `$_POST['upc']`?

Comment: edited to show where $_POST['upc'] is created

Comment: I think I saw it... the for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) should be for($i=0; $i<=20; $i++)?... Although I don't think it would change anything since they are not exactly correlated.  Not sure, been trying to figure it out for a while.  @Darren -> It happens on isolated cases, and the problem is that it can't happen since I'm working on an inventory table. So I cant have errors :(

Comment: Could you show the example data in `$_POST['upc']` ?

Comment: Are you sure that $upc is always four elements in length, or that one or more of them isn't coming back null? For what it's worth, "trusting" user input is generally a bad idea... and you should be 1) checking the length of $upc is what you expect and 2) sanitizing that data to make sure nothing "stray" gets embedded (like a '\'; DELETE FROM inventory WHERE 1;')

Comment: @RVT -> I think I am sanitizing the data and in this particular case $upc is always 20, but not all of them have to have data.  I have another page running with a conditional for fields in which you can actually select how many fields you will modify, but in this particular case I have to have 20 as the default as this is a page in which 99.9% of the time 20 items will be inserted and a deduction from the database will happen. But thank you and yes I will anyway check to make sure I'm sanitizing :p

Comment: @user3701157 ... you might also try adding in debug code to see what's getting updated, prior to your redirect. Essentially something that prints out each index as it's updating, along with the return code (if any) from MySQL... or at least the updated row count (ie. `print mysql_affected_rows($mysqli)`).

Comment: @RVT -> didn't think of this, yeah I can run it manually for a while to see in which instances they don't update and maybe I can then pinpoint the error. Thanks, will try this.

Comment: @RVT -> I have noticed that everytime I run the function it will jump 1 row... update -1 -> 9 9 10 then on the next run -> 8 9 9 -> 7 9 8 -> 6 8 7 etc.  The first row will always be modified, ignore the second, modify third, then second row will be modified, ignore third and so on.

Comment: Sorry @user3701157 ... I went off on vacation for a bit. Have you solved this one, by chance? Sounds like there was a double-increment happening in the code somewhere?

Comment: @RVT yes I did, the problem was that I had another simultaneous query running that was locking the table, what I never did understand even though I later tried to figure it out was why the -1 or +1 scenario in which it updated a row then skipped and then on the next run it would skip another and so on... Anyway, thanks RVT for the help :)